# JQ: How to join arrays by key?

Tags: jq

How can I expand array with a category stored in a dictionary?

E.g. for the following input,

```
{"weigths":
  [
    {"name":"apple","weigth":200},
    {"name":"tomato", "weigth":100}
  ],
 "categories":
 [
   {"name":"apple","category":"fruit"},
   {"name":"tomato","category":"vegetable"}
 ]
}
```

I need a performance-efficient way to append respective `category` to each object in `weights`, resulting in output:

```
{"weigths":
  [
    {"name":"apple","weigth":200, "category": "fruit"},
    {"name":"tomato", "weigth":100, "category": "vegetable"}
  ],
}
```

Is it something for `JOIN/4`? (I never tried it)

---

**Update:**

Ideally I would like to deal with a not-that-SQL object for categories: full input looking like this

```
{"weigths":
  [
    {"name":"apple","weigth":200},
    {"name":"orange", "weigth":300}
    {"name":"tomato","weigth":100},
    {"name":"spinach","weigth":50},
  ],
 "categories":
 {
   "fruit": ["apple", "orange"],
   "vegetable": ["tomato", "spinach"]
 }
}
```

...still getting a similar output:

```
{"weigths":
  [
    {"name": "apple", "weigth": 200, "category": "fruit"},
    {"name": "orange", "weigth": 300, "category": "fruit"},
    {"name": "tomato", "weigth": 100, "category": "vegetable"}
    {"name": "spinach", "weigth": 50, "category": "vegetable"}
  ],
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the SQL-Style Operators `JOIN` and `INDEX` would be:

```bash
{weights: [JOIN(INDEX(.categories[]; .name); .weigths[]; .name; add)]}
```

```json
{
  "weights": [
    {
      "name": "apple",
      "weigth": 200,
      "category": "fruit"
    },
    {
      "name": "tomato",
      "weigth": 100,
      "category": "vegetable"
    }
  ]
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/nqTWNhB3KyT)

---

For the updated structure, the `INDEX` of `.categories` needs to be tweaked (e.g. employing `to_entries`) in order to provide the `.key` as `.category` for each array item:

```bash
{weights: [JOIN(
  # INDEX(.categories[]; .name);    # This has been replaced with:
    INDEX(.categories | to_entries[]; .value[]) | .[] |= {category: .key};
.weigths[]; .name; add)]}
```

```json
{
  "weights": [
    {
      "name": "apple",
      "weigth": 200,
      "category": "fruit"
    },
    {
      "name": "orange",
      "weigth": 300,
      "category": "fruit"
    },
    {
      "name": "tomato",
      "weigth": 100,
      "category": "vegetable"
    },
    {
      "name": "spinach",
      "weigth": 50,
      "category": "vegetable"
    }
  ]
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/aeS2eLhojD5)

Comment: Thank you so much! Any chance for the updated part (under the "Update:" in the question)?

Comment: @wassrubleff To be honest, I don't understand the update question. Where should `orange` and `spinach` come from? Are you perhaps looking for a grouping like `jq '.categories | group_by(.category) | map({(first.category): map(.name)}) | {categories: add}'`?

Comment: Expanded the update with a full input data.

Comment: @wassrubleff Yet, you didn't explain where the two new values should come from. Maybe the input you provide is different from the one you are using? Did you try `group_by` from my previous comment? With that, use `|=` to update (and not just to query) in order to retain the original structure: `jq '.categories |= (group_by(.category) | map({(first.category): map(.name)}) | add)'`.

Comment: The update is about having a different input: a separate list for all items to be categorized as fruits, another list of items to be categorized as vegetables. This is the input I actually have; I'm curious whether there is more performance-efficient way to process that data.

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in checking out ~Q (pronounced "unquery"), a query language that I very recently released, that just like jq can run as a command-line tool.

https://github.com/xcite-db/Unquery

In the first case, the query would be:

```
{
    "#var cat:categories[]": {
          "$(name)":"category"
    },
    "#return:weigths[]": [{
       "{}:" : ".",
       "category":"$var(cat).$(name)"
    }]
}
```

And in the updated example, the query is:

```
{
    "#var cat: categories:{}:[]": {
          "$(.)": "$key"
    },
    "#return:weigths[]": [{
       "{}:": ".",
       "category":"$var(cat).$(name)"
    }]
}
```

In either case, the trick is to start by generating a map from fruits to categories, and then use this map to add the category to each entry. So the difference is only in the first part (generating the map).

A variable in ~Q can contain any JSON value/document. The code:

```
    "#var cat: categories:{}:[]": {
          "$(.)": "$key"
    },
```

Converts `categories` in-memory into:

```
{
    "apple": "fruit",
    "orange": "fruit",
    "spinach": "vegetable",
    "tomato": "vegetable"
}
```

And after that, you can use it to retrieve the category with `$var(cat).$(name)`. If you have a different structure for categories, all you need to do is to change that part of the code to generate the mapping from the categories structure.